# UITextField within UISearchBar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, ios7, uisearchbar

I am trying to accomplish the same look of my UISearchBar with a TextField within it, as in my iOS 6 app. I have tried to code it in several ways and not yet been successful. The problem is, I am not able to change the TextField's frame in any way since iOS 7. The result is, my TextField takes all the space in the NavigationBar and overrides the UIBarButtonItem (menu button) to the right. See pictures below:

[image: Screenshots]

***iOS 6 code:*** *This is how I coded it in iOS 6, where I could set the TextFields frame to whatever I liked!*

```
UITextField *sbTextField = (UITextField *)[searchBar.subviews lastObject];
[sbTextField removeFromSuperview];

CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
rect.size.height = 32;
rect.size.width = 210;
sbTextField.frame = rect;

[sbTextField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];


UIBarButtonItem *searchBarNavigationItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithCustomView:sbTextField];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:searchBarNavigationItem];
```

**The result from the code above in iOS 7:** ![iOS 7 look]

***iOS 7 code:*** *The difference in iOS 7, is that you need to use subViews in order to add the UITextField to the UISearchBar/UINavigationBar. By doing this I have not yet been able to change its frame. It currently overlaps the menuButton to the right which can be seen in the picture below this code...*

```
UITextField* sbTextField;
CGRect rect = subView.frame;
rect.size.height = 32;
rect.size.width = 115;

for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews){
    for (UIView *ndLeveSubView in subView.subviews){

        if ([ndLeveSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {

            sbTextField = (UITextField *)ndLeveSubView;
            sbTextField.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
            UIBarButtonItem *searchBarNavigationItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sbTextField];
            sbTextField.frame = rect;
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchBarNavigationItem;
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  menuButton;
            [sbTextField removeFromSuperview];

             break;
        }

    }

 }
 [self.searchBar reloadInputViews];
```

[image]
SO...Is it possible to change a subView's frame (TextField) in any way ? :(

**EDIT**

*The answer is kinda lame. In order to make the code work in ios7 with a button to the right of the TextField, the TextField must be set as the titleView of the navigationBar. Which was not the case in ios 6. But there will be other glitches and it is not recommended to use TextField within searchBars in iOS7. Use searchDispalyController instead. Se my answer below*

```
 self.navigationItem.titleView = sbTextField;
```

Comment: See my answer below - your approach is not consistent with the iOS 7 design guidelines, and you're reinventing the wheel.  Apple already provides a widget to embed a UISearchBar in a UINavigationBar. One line of code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19185272/1103584

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanx to spotdog13. I finally managed to make it work for iOS 7 properly in the following way:

```
#define TABLE_BOTTOM_MARGIN 5
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize searchResults;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {


    [searchBar sizeToFit]; // standard size
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    // Add search bar to navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    }
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
// Manually activate search mode
// Use animated=NO so we'll be able to immediately un-hide it again
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:NO];
// Hand over control to UISearchDisplayController during the search
// searchBar.delegate = (id <UISearchBarDelegate>)self.searchDisplayController;

return YES;
}

#pragma mark <UISearchDisplayDelegate>
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController
 // Un-hide the navigation bar that UISearchDisplayController hid
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}

- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController
                                           *)controller {
searchBar = (UISearchBar *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
// Manually resign search mode
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
// Take back control of the search bar
searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: In what way would it be a problem ? As I see it, both ways are acceptable.

Answer (score 13):

in iOS 7 to access Text Field you have to reiterate on level more. Change your code like this

```
for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews){
    for (UIView *ndLeveSubView in subView.subviews){
    if ([ndLeveSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)ndLeveSubView;
            break;
        }
    }
   }
```

But best way to clear backgournd of UISearchBar and setting searchbar icon in text field is:

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] ];//if you want to remove background of uisearchbar
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"search_icon.png"];
[searchBar setImage:image forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. The code is working the same way as my old one did, but I am not able to reposition the search-icon + text within the textfield or the size of it :(

Comment: Create UiImageView with requried frame and set it to the textField.leftView.

Comment: Not working if I am not doing anything wrong. Seems like a nobel price to get a simple textfield as you wish in iOS 7.... How would you code it? Have you tried it or seen anyone else do it in ios7 ?

Comment: Well, I don't understand how this would solve my problem. In iOS 6 setting the textField's frame would do the trick, but it is not listening to it anymore? I have also tried to programmatically add textField in search bars left space and the menuButton in the right space. Still the textField just takes all the space in the searchbar: self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchBarNavigationItem;
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  self.menuButton;

Comment: Was able to get the `UITextField` within the `UISearchBar` but it renders the search bar unusable for some reason. Doesn't show anything that I type in.

Answer (score 13):

You should not put a `UITextField` in the `UINavigationBar` in iOS 7, this widget is already provided by Apple.

In iOS 7, you can simply use a `UISearchDisplayController` with a `UISearchBar`, and set:

```
searchDisplayController.displaySearchBarInNavigationBar = YES
```

The search bar will appear in your `UINavigationBar`, and it will play nice with the other `UIBarButtonItem`s without all the hacks and manual frame sizing in your original iOS 6 solution.

One thing to note - if you are going to add this to a project that still supports OSes older than iOS 7, you'll want to make sure that you put a check around the call or your app will crash when running on older OSes.

```
if([searchDisplayController respondsToSelector:@selector(displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar)])
{
    searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
}
```

See this section of the iOS 7 transition guide: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html

> In iOS 7, UISearchDisplayController includes the
>   displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar property, which you can use to put a
>   search bar in a navigation bar, similar to the one in Calendar on
>   iPhone:

One other note - you should consider migrating to AutoLayout going forward so you don't have to do all that tedious frame manipulation.  Apple recommends it, and probably for good reason (future devices with larger screens...?)

Comment: is this backwards compatible to ios6?

Comment: No.  If you want to use this in an app that supports older OSes as well, you'll need to put a check around the displaySearchBarInNavigationBar = YES call or the app will crash.  I'll update my answer with details.

Answer (score 2):

Create a UIView *textFieldContainer with your target frame, add your textfield to that UIView and then add that textFieldContainer as a navigation item. i.e. your approach remains the same just the textfield comes inside a container and you play with that container.

Comment: This is by far the best and easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this out i am not sure but this should work as in iOS 7 searchbar has subview and inside that subview there are two subviews one of which is UITextField

```
UIView *searchbarview = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
UITextField *sbTextField = (UITextField *)[searchbarview.subviews lastObject];
[sbTextField removeFromSuperview];

CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
rect.size.height = 32;
rect.size.width = 210;
sbTextField.frame = rect;

[sbTextField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];


UIBarButtonItem *searchBarNavigationItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sbTextField];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:searchBarNavigationItem];
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS6 & iOS7 compatible solution:

```
- (void)setTextFieldAsDelegate:(UIView *)inputView {
    for (UIView *view in inputView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)view;
            searchBarTextField.delegate = self;
            break;
        } else {
            [self setTextFieldAsDelegate:view];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift solution

```
for subView in searchBar.subviews{
        for deeperView in subView.subviews{
            if let searchField:UITextField = deeperView as? UITextField{
                searchField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                searchField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 134/255, green: 14/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
                searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            }
        }
    }
```