# Make uisearchbar look like uiinputfield

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I've got a `UISearchBar` that behaves like a `UITextField` in terms that it's part of a form in an app. Therefor I'd like to make it look like all the other (non background, non border, non logo, just placeholder) fields.

How do I do this?

**Edit**

I've got a searchbar that looks like this: http://cl.ly/image/0W0n223Q2e2V
But now i've got to get rid of the search icon and the bacground view + customize the placeholder text. How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008155/uitextfield-within-uisearchbar-in-ios-7/19183386#19183386 . This might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will help you attain that borderless boring look:

```
[searchBarObject setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];

//might need this as well
[searchBarObject setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

---

Note: You can continue using `UISearchBarStyleDefault`
**or...**
You could **not** do any of the above and instead utilize `UISearchBarStyleMinimal` to get a borderless but with a slight background look.

Comment: This does not work :( I'm using storyboards.. Might that have anything to do with it?

Comment: it should. it worked for me or else i would not have posted an answer. erm... what happens for you?

Comment: I doens't change anything. It stayed just like the picture I posted in the update/edit.

Comment: @bdv : that's because you're using `UISearchBarStyleMinimal`. Switch to `UISearchBarStyleDefault` and check.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the `searchbarStyle` property:

```
UISearchBarStyleDefault,
UISearchBarStyleProminent,
UISearchBarStyleMinimal
```

and the appearance methods. Check the [UISearchBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/searchBarStyle)